# Trim part of a string in dataframe

Tags: regex, r, replace, trim

If I have a dataframe structure like that:

```
AA1_123.zip
BB2_456.txt
CCC_789.doc
```

How can I change it to this:

```
AA1
BB2
CCC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the strings are all the same style at the start, three characters before the underline, this will work:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col = c("AA1_123.zip", "BB2_456.txt", 
                              "CCC_789.doc"
)), .Names = "Col", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

> substr(df1$Col, 1, 3)
[1] "AA1" "BB2" "CCC"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try `sub`

```
sub('_.*', '', df1$Col)
#[1] "AA1" "BB2" "CCC"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col = c("AA1_123.zip", "BB2_456.txt", 
"CCC_789.doc"
)), .Names = "Col", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also read the column again, using `comment.char = "_"` to flush the rest of the line.  Y

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("AA1_123.zip", "BB2_456.txt", "CCC_789.doc"))

read.table(text = as.character(df$x), comment.char="_")
#    V1
# 1 AA1
# 2 BB2
# 3 CCC
```

Or you can use `scan()`

```
scan(text = as.character(df$x), what = "", comment.char="_")
# Read 3 items
# [1] "AA1" "BB2" "CCC"
```